# How to close, exit or dismiss Decimal Pad when I click outside a textfield?

Tags: swift, xcode

My Swift app required the user to enter decimal values on a UITextfield.  The Decimal Pad appears when the user click inside the textfield. Then the user enter the amount and click the Calculate Button to see results.

I want to close the Decimal Pad when the user click outside the de UITextfield or outside the keyboard.

My App looks like this:
[image: My App]

This is my first app in Swift (Xcode).  So I'm newbie.  Please try to recommend a code.

I am doing something wrong.  :(

[image: The error]

Comment: create and gesture on your main view and in the function setup         self.view.endEditing(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

1- Create a Tab Gesture Recognizer from the object library (+) to the main View.

2- Create an @IBAction connection in the functions area of the program.  This step automatically creates this.

```
@IBAction func dismissKeyboard(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

3- Add a blank line in that function to include this line:

```
@IBAction func dismissKeyboard(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)  // The added line
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the IQKeyboardManager library, it will solve all your keyboard problems. A "Close" button will appear above the keyboard, a tap outside the keyboard to hide will also work in any controller without additional settings

Comment: Can you tell me how to download IQKeyboardManager library.

Comment: take a look here:- https://cocoapods.org/pods/IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Answer (score 0):

as comment given by: cristian_064

step: 1 - create `IBOutlet` of the `UIView`

```
@IBOutlet weak var vwParent: UIView!
```

step: 2 - assign tap gesture to `UIView`

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
vwParent.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

step: 2 - create an event handler(`@objc`) method for handling the operation when `UIView` is tapped.

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
   self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: This is too difficult to me.  I try your recommendation but I'm doing something wrong.  Please see my error screen.

Comment: add step - 2 solution inside `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: if still error not resolved then you can drop your mail-id, I'll send the solution asap :)